# How to change style of DragPreviewImage when it's hovering DropTarget in react-dnd reactjs?

Tags: reactjs, drag-and-drop, react-dnd, react-beautiful-dnd

I want change DragPreviewImage style, example: scale, fill color, change opacity when it's hovering over DragTarget! 
Here is my short version example code:

**1. DragPhoto component:**

```
import React from 'react'
import { useDrag, DragPreviewImage } from 'react-dnd'

type DraggablePhotoProps = {
  photoItem: any,
  datasource: string
}

export const DraggablePhoto = (props: DraggablePhotoProps) => {

  const [{isDragging}, drag, preview] = useDrag({
    item: { type: props.datasource },
    isDragging: (monitor) => {
      console.log("Draggable Photo: isDragging" )
      return true
    },
    collect: monitor => ({
      isDragging: !!monitor.isDragging(),
    })
  })

  return (
    <>
      <DragPreviewImage connect={preview} src={props.photoItem['preview']} ref={previewRef} />
      <img src={props.photoItem['preview']}
        ref={drag}
        style={{opacity: isDragging ? 0 : 1}}
      />
    </>
  )

}
```

**2. DragTarget component:**

```
import React from 'react'
import { useDrop } from 'react-dnd'

export const CanvasContainer = (props) => {
  const [{ isOver, canDrop }, drop] = useDrop({
    accept: "upload_photo",
    drop: () => {
      console.log('CanvasContainer drop')
    },
    canDrop: () => { return true },
    hover: (item, monitor) => {
      console.log('CanvasContainer hover')
    },
    collect: (monitor) => ({
      isOver: !!monitor.isOver(),
      canDrop: !!monitor.canDrop()
    })
  })

  return (
    <div ref={drop} style={{width: '100%', height: '100%'}}>
      { props.children}
    </div>
  )

})
```

How to change style of DragPreviewImage when it's hovering over div tag ?

Thank you!

Comment: did you ever figure this out?